# invalidate form if grid doesn't have rows - DevExtreme grid - Angular

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

how to make a form invalid if a grid(DxDataGridModule) of DevExtreme framework doesn't have any row?

the grid is in row editing mode so the status of the `myFormVariable.form.valid` should change if i add or remove rows to the grid

```
<form  #myFormVariable="ngForm" id="frm_create_user" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
.....
...
</form>
```

Comment: At what point do you check for validity of form.

Comment: on a my button click event

Answer (score 0):

I presume this save() method is called after the form was deemed valid. In this method simpy check if the grid is empty and report an error to the user.

```
function save(){
   var gridData = $("#grid").dxDataGrid().dxDataGrid("instance").option("dataSource");
   if(gridData == null || gridData.length == 0)
   {
      //Report the error to the user
      return;
   }
   //Code that issues a request to the server
}
```

I made a quick example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rprimora/pen/VQrBoO). I have copied the example from [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/Validation/jQuery/Light/) and adjusted it so a grid is also present. This is just to give you a general idea of how to do.